# Where can I find my draft questions?

Tags: support, draft

I just published a question on Stack Overflow. Just after that, I came across another problem. So I wrote another question. But I could not publish it because of the 90-min limit. So I waited for 90 min but then I lost what I have written. Where can I find that question draft?

Comment: Drafts aren't saved properly AFAIK. If it doesn't show up in the editor, it's lost.

Comment: Relevant information about drafts: [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/268911)

Comment: [You can only save one draft at a time and its wonky to but click "Ask Question" to return to your last draft.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting)

Answer (score 9):

As soon as you leave the page where you are typing your question, a draft of it is saved. This even works if you log out and log in again.
But you will only find your last draft. I don't think there is somewhere a function hidden, where you can find all your drafts, as there is no function to save a draft manually.

Comment: Huh, that's actually true. There used to be a "save draft" button under the input field, but that must've been removed recently.

Comment: This works for answers too, and if you're using Google Chrome with Sync turned on, it works across devices. I once started typing an answer on my work PC during my lunch break, and then finished and posted it on my home PC later that night.

Comment: I guess I've been doing it all wrong then. I write it on paper, just to be sure my draft is never lost. It's only really a hazzle when compiling it, but I guess [I'm not the first with that particular problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers)

Comment: @Scratte This is the first time I've been graced by a link to that, that's amazing.

Comment: That is technically true but I wouldn't trust drafts on SO because the behavior seems inconsistent. If I might go back later to a question/answer that I decided not to post yet, I always copy it to a text file or something.

Comment: They should do one imo. Give you the possibility to save drafts for up to 3 questions or sth.